# How to login with facebook SDK Xamarin Android?

Tags: android, facebook, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to use the Facebook SDK to login with Facebook in a Android application. But I got a problem with `IFacebookCallback`.

```C#
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
{   
    base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.SdkInitialize (Application.Context);
    // Create your application here
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.LoginLayout);

    callbackManager = CallbackManagerFactory.Create ();

    loginButton = FindViewById<LoginButton> (Resource.Id.btnloginbyfacebook);

    LoginManager.Instance.RegisterCallback (callbackManager, new IFacebookCallback<LoginResult> ()
        {
        }
    );

    loginButton.SetReadPermissions("user_friends");
    loginButton.SetReadPermissions("public_profile");
    loginButton.SetReadPermissions("email");
    loginButton.SetReadPermissions("user_birthday");
}
```

I got this error:

**Error the non- generic type IFacebookCallback cannot be used with type arguments.**

Comment: Were you able to use the Facebook SDK for login successfully ? I am facing some issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IFacebookCallback` is an interface. You can't create an instance of an interface. You must implement that interface and then pass to the             `LoginManager.Instance.RegisterCallback (callbackManager, new FacebookCallbackImplementation());`

Example of the implementation for facebook `4.16.1`:

```
class FacebookCallbackImplementation<LoginResult> : Java.Lang.Object, IFacebookCallback where LoginResult : Java.Lang.Object
{
    public void OnSuccess(Java.Lang.Object obj){

        if (obj != null) {  
            var loginResult = obj.JavaCast<LoginResult>();
            AccessToken accesstoken = loginResult.AccessToken; 
        }
    }

    public void OnCancel(){ }

    public void OnError(FacebookException fbException){ }
}
```

**As alternative** you can get here a generic way to implement the [IFacebookCallback](https://gist.github.com/rmenezes/d1a98e18f19c6555c6c2).

---

For facebook versions above `4.16.1` as per [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/upgrading-4x) there are littles changes when retrieving `AccessToken`:

These as the changes proposed in `OnSuccess`:

```
public void OnSuccess(Java.Lang.Object obj)
{
    if (AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken != null)
    {
        var profile = Profile.CurrentProfile;
    }
}
```

Additional Note: Sometimes after `OnSuccess` the `Profile` is still `null` for dealing with that edge cases take a look at `ProfileTracker` to [watch](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/accesstokens) profile changes.

Comment: getAccessToken() method of variable loginResult is not available.

Comment: Updated my answer, please check it.

Comment: I don't see any update! still your code contains call to method getAccessToken();

Comment: Maybe its due to a different version from the library. can you share with me your sample of it?

Comment: I have the same proglem with getAccessToken() method does not exists. Even if I try `loginResult.AccessToken` I get an error. If I stop the debugger there I see loginResult has variable AccessToken. Any ideas how to get it from the object?

Comment: @Micer Note that ´AccessToken´ is a ´property´ not a ´method´. This was tested in Facebook sdk 4.16.1.

Comment: `getAccessToken` is a java property. In C#, it is `AccessToken`.